# Routing breaks when lazy loading another module

Tags: angular

I have a lazy loaded module `AccountModule` which gets loaded after accessing https://localhost:4201/account.

**app.routing.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ui/pages/start/start.module')
      .then(m => m.StartModule)
  },


  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./ui/pages/account/account.module')
      .then(m => m.AccountModule)
  },

];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: false,
  enableTracing: false
});
```

`AccountModule` has two child routes. One of which gets loaded eagerly (`/overview`) whereas the other gets loaded lazily (`/albums`).

Hence, **acount.routing.ts** looks like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full'},

  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: AccountComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'albums',
    loadChildren: () => import('./albums/albums.module').then(m => m.AlbumsModule),
    // component: AlbumsComponent  // This works!
  },

];

export const AccountRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Now, if I use "eager" loading (`component:AlbumsComponent`) everything is working. But, if I switch to `loadChildren: () => ...` routing does not work anymore. This `routerLink`

```xml
<app-raised-button [routerLink]="['/account/albums']">
  My Albums
</app-raised-button>
```

Results in https://localhost:4201/account/albums (working) or https://localhost:4201/account/albums/overview (not working). But why? And how can I fix this issue?

Why does it behave differently just because of the way the module/component gets loaded?

---

If I am setting the path to `./albums`:

```js
{
  path: './albums',
  loadChildren: () => import('./albums/albums.module').then(m => m.AlbumsModule),
},
```

I am just getting

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: `'account/albums'`

Comment: What happens if you try:  ```loadChildren: './albums/albums.module#AlbumsModule'``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have not provided a Routes for albums.routing.module ?

Since you have directed the albums.module, but you might have not provided from there what component you have been show.

If you have not created to albums.routing.module, create one and provide a default route in the same module.

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path: '', component:AlbumsComponent } ];
```

Comment: +facepalm+ .. yes, this was indeed the problem. I forgot to provide routes for the module.. Thanks for helping!

Comment: glad to help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your albums module , you have your have imported your routes as shown : ***RouterModule.forChild(albumsRoutes)***

Comment: Nope, still getting `account/albums/overview` - no idea why this happens ..

Comment: Make sure in your albums module , you have your have imported your route as **RouterModule.forChild(albumsRoutes)**